# Go back to beginning of code in jquery and html

Tags: jquery, html, hide, reset

When i press a button on my code i want to go back to the beginning of the code so i can do the code all over again. For example if i had this in html:

```
<div id='a'></div>
<div id='b'></div>
<div id='c'></div>
<div id='d'></div>
```

and then the the jquery looked like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').click(function(){
      $('#a').hide();
      $('#b').toggle(400)
      $('#c').css('margin', '100px)
    });
 });
```

how could i get it so after the user clicks on a, a b and c disappear, but then a b and c show up again after they click on d to do it all over again

Comment: Have 'd' reload the page.

Comment: @LeeMeador yes but i would also like me to be able to count how many times a hid.. are there any other ways??

Comment: You can reload the page with a query parm holding the count updated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use this function:

```
$('#d').click(function(){
  $('#a').show();
  $('#b').toggle(400)
  $('#c').css('margin', '0px)
});
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QRw9q/)

```
<div class="toHide" id="a">a</div>
<div class="toHide">b</div>
<div class="toHide">c</div>
<div id="d">d</div>


 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#a').click(function(){
      $(".toHide").hide();
    });
     $('#d').click(function(){
      $(".toHide").show();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('#d').click(function(){
  $('#a').show();
  $('#b').show();
  $('#c').css('margin', '0');
});
```

You could also save the initial state (by looping over them) using the data API:

```
 $("#a").data("original-state", $("<div></div>").html($("#a").clone())).html());
```

And restore it afterwards with:

```
$("#a").replaceWith($("#a").data("original-state"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I first would use on instead of click (else it will not work with my method).

I would aswell save a "template". So DOM ready code would look like that :

```
var template;
$(document).ready(function(){
    template = $('body').html();
    $(document).on('click', '#a', function(){
      $('#a').hide();
      $('#b').toggle(400)
      $('#c').css('margin', '100px)
    });
});
```

And i'd add that event :

```
$(document).on('click', '#d', function(){
    $('body').html(template)
})
```

Change `$('body')` for the parent container of you button.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to do this.
But if you want the id="d" to be show you can just add class "button" to it.
Always remember to use class for this technique.

```
<div id='a' class="button"></div>
<div id='b' class="button"></div>
<div id='c' class="button"></div>
<div id='d' class="reset"></div>
```

and jQuery will be

```
$(".button").click(function(){
  $(".button").not(this).hide("slow");
});
$("#d").click(function(){
  $(".button").show("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with the following: http://jsfiddle.net/e57F9/1/

```
<div class="foo">
    <div id='a'>a</div>
    <div id='b'>b</div>
    <div id='c'>c</div>
    <div id='d'>d</div>
</div>
```

The use this to reset

```
// Make an original copy just in case they click 'd' first
var originalHtml = $(".foo").clone();
var clearCount = 0;
$(document).on("click", "#a", function(){
  // Backup the state right before clicking
  originalHtml = $(".foo").clone();
  $("#a").hide();
  $("#b").toggle(400);
  $("#c").css("margin", "100px");
});
$(document).on("click", "#d", function () {
  // Restore the object
  $(".foo").replaceWith(originalHtml.clone());
  clearCount++;
});
```